# I need to open a desired email using selenium python ,can anyone tell me how can i select desired email from my gmail grid

Tags: python, selenium, email

I am making automated mail forwarding system and I need to open the desired email using selenium python, can anyone tell me how can I select the desired email from my Gmail grid, then I have to forward it to someone email. is this possible to select the desired email which I want to forward using selenium automation library in python?
I try to select the desired email using ID, Class, XPath but still, an error occurs that "The tags cannot locate".

[image of grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmzq3.jpg)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


# credintials
username_for_email = "xxx@gmail.com"
password_for_email = "xxx"
driverpath = "E:\\New folder (2)\\chromedriver.exe"

# driver path for chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverpath)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/gmail/")

   # email username
  try:
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId")
        elem.send_keys(username_for_email)
        # next_btn_for_email = 
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('CwaK9').click()
        next_btn_for_email = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierNext')
        next_btn_for_email.click()
        time.sleep(3)
  except:
       raise SystemError("Your email value get mismatched")

try:
    password_field = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    password_field.send_keys(password_for_email)
    next_btn_for_password = 
    driver.find_element_by_id('passwordNext').click()
    time.sleep(100)
except:
    raise SystemError("password is wrong!")

   #selct_email_for_sent = Select(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//* 
  [@id=":6h"]')).select_by_index(2)
   #sent_email = (driver.find_element_by_class_name('y6')) and 
   (driver.find_element_by_id(':3c')) and 
   driver.find_element_by_tag_name('').click()
   sent_mail = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id=":3t"]').
  driver.close()
```

Comment: If you made some trials at your end, then share it in your question description. Read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to understand how to ask a proper question.

Comment: @Manmohan_singh i made changes ! is it clear?